# Daily Sum, Month To Date, MTD Avg, Prev Month Avg

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum, average

Please help me in a problem related to SUM, AVG, MTD SUM about finding Oil Volumes flow through meters in Facilities.

Say, there are two Facilities

1. NORTH - having meters N1, N2
2. SOUTH - having meters S1, S2

There is a daily flow through the meters. Table FACILITY_OIL looks like following -

```
TimeStamp----------Facility----------Meter----------OilVolume

10-SEP-2014    |   NORTH        |    N1       |     100

10-SEP-2014    |   NORTH        |    N2       |     200

10-SEP-2014    |   SOUTH        |    S1       |     300

10-SEP-2014    |   SOUTH        |    S2       |     400


10-OCT-2014    |   NORTH        |    N1       |     100

10-OCT-2014    |   NORTH        |    N2       |     200

10-OCT-2014    |   SOUTH        |    S1       |     300

10-OCT-2014    |   SOUTH        |    S2       |     400

11-OCT-2014    |   NORTH        |    N1       |     400

11-OCT-2014    |   NORTH        |    N2       |     300

11-OCT-2014    |   SOUTH        |    S1       |     200

11-OCT-2014    |   SOUTH        |    S2       |     100

12-OCT-2014    |   NORTH        |    N1       |     100

12-OCT-2014    |   NORTH        |    N2       |     200

12-OCT-2014    |   SOUTH        |    S1       |     300

12-OCT-2014    |   SOUTH        |    S2       |     400
```

I have to find following grouped by facility:

1. Sum of Oil Volume through all Meters in a Facility on a given day.
2. Month to Date sum of Oil Volume through meters.
3. Average of MTD Oil Volume
4. Previous Month Average of Oil Volume

Output should look like following on 12-OCT

```
Facility-----DailySum-----MTD_Sum-----MTD_Avg-----Prev_Month_Avg

NORTH    |   300     |    1300    |   108.33   |  10

SOUTH    |   700     |    1700    |   141.66   |  23.33

Here for NORTH on 12-OCT,

DailySum = (N1+N2)

MTD SUM = (N1 + N2) from 01-Oct to 12-Oct

MTD_Avg = MTD_SUM/12days

Pre_Month_Avg = (100+200)/30
```

Is it possible to output in the same format. My limitations are I cant use SP. It has to be from a view.

I tried using group by but was not able to achieve it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks a ton!

---

Thanks for your help!

It seems to work perfect for one day. I was able to use your query.

I added 'with rollup' to get the sum at the end. However, the requirement now changed to get the dataset for each of the day. So it should look like following:

```
Timestamp--Facility--DailySum--MTD_Sum--MTD_Avg--Prev_Month_Avg
10-Oct | NORTH | 300 | 1300 | 108.33 | 10
10-Oct | SOUTH | 700 | 1700 | 141.66 | 23.33
10-Oct | TOTAL | 1000| 3000 | 249.99 | 33.33

12-Oct | NORTH | 300 | 1300 | 108.33 | 10
12-Oct | SOUTH | 700 | 1700 | 141.66 | 23.33
12-Oct | TOTAL | 1000| 3000 | 249.99 | 33.33
```

I tried modified query from yours-

```
select case when null then 'TOTAL' else Facility end as 'Facility'
,sum(case when [TimeStamp]>=dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,getdate()),0) then OilVolume else 0 end) as DailySum
,sum(case when [TimeStamp]>=dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0) then OilVolume else 0 end) as MTD_Sum
,sum(case when [TimeStamp]>=dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0) then OilVolume else 0 end)/datepart(dd,getdate()) as MTD_Avg
,sum(case when [TimeStamp]>=dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate()),0) then 0 else OilVolume end)/datepart(dd,dateadd(dd,datepart(dd,getdate())*-1,getdate())) as Prev_Month_Avg
from yourtable
where [TimeStamp]>=dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,getdate())-1,0)
group by Timestamp, Facility with rollup
```

It doesn't seem to work with simple group by. I am not sure how to get the repeating result for one day. I cannot use CURSOR or loop n a view. Please help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use case for that

```
select
sum(case when timestamp = '12-OCT-2014' then meter + oilVolume else 0 end),
sum(case when timestamp between '01-OCT-2014' and '12-OCT-2014' then meter + volume else 0 end),
sum(case when timestamp between  '01-OCT-2014' and '12-OCT-2014' then meter + volume else 0 end) / datediff("dd",'01-OCT-2014' , '12-OCT-2014'),
sum(case when timestamp between '01-SEP-2014' and '30-SEP-2014' then meter + volume  else 0 end ) / datediff("dd",'01-SEP-2014' , '30-SEP-2014')
from ...
```

you could change your date with parameters.

Comment: Thanks for help! I didn't know SUM can be used so cleverly. When I add group by clause to your query, it seem to work as expected!